# Reducing / Enhancing known features in an image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mahotas

I am microbiology student new to computer vision, so any help will be extremely appreciated.

This question involves microscope images that I am trying to analyze. The goal I am trying to accomplish is to count bacteria in an image but I need to pre-process the image first to enhance any bacteria that are not fluorescing very brightly. I have thought about using several different techniques like enhancing the contrast or sharpening the image but it isn't exactly what I need.

I want to reduce the noise(black spaces) to 0's on the RBG scale and enhance the green spaces. I originally was writing a for loop in OpenCV with threshold limits to change each pixel but I know that there is a better way.

Here is an example that I did in photo shop of the original image vs what I want.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0oDx.jpg) and [enhanced Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Gwd.jpg).

I need to learn to do this in a python environment so that I can automate this process. As I said I am new but I am familiar with python's OpenCV, mahotas, `numpy` etc. so I am not exactly attached to a particular package. I am also very new to these techniques so I am open to even if you just point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially tried histogram equalization but did not get the desired results. So I used **adaptive threshold** using the **mean filter**:

`th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 3, 2)`
[image]

Then I applied the **median filter**:

`median = cv2.medianBlur(th, 5)`
[image]

Finally I applied **morphological closing** with the ellipse kernel:

```
k1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(median, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k1, 3)
```

[image]

[THIS PAGE](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) will help you modify this result however you want.

Comment: Hi Jeru, I am getting an error about the adaptive thresholding. It says                <ipython-input-7-9b10f2c1a780> in <module>()
----> 1 th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 3, 2)

error: /feedstock_root/build_artefacts/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:1286: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function adaptiveThreshold

Comment: Hi Jeru, thank you for the awesome post! This is in response to my previous comment up above. I want to add for anyone who is trying to follow this that I had to incorporate the following code on the image  `img = img.max(axis=2)` in order to do the thresholding.

Comment: @Bryce Yes that's right, because adaptive threshold works only for gray scale images :D

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization). This would emphasize the green and reduce the black range. There is an OpenCV tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html). Afterwards you can experiment with different [thresholding mechanisms](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) that best yields the bacteria.

Comment: Thanks ilke444, I I have never tried that approach before and so it was a great learning experience! After playing around with your suggestion on my images I would say it was close, but not quite what I needed. I really appreciate your input and I know I will use this later on in my image analysis career.

Answer (score 1):

Use TensorFlow:

1. create your own dataset with images of bacteria and their positions stored in accompanying text files (the bigger the dataset the better).
2. Create a positive and negative set of images
3. update default TensorFlow example with your images
4. make sure you have a bunch of convolution layers.
5. train and test.

TensorFlow is perfect for such tasks and you don't need to worry about different intensity levels.